# Clojure: korma database error

Tags: clojure, korma

So I am using mariadb, I have already made my database and connected it with korma, the database has permission set i (think) have all the drivers installed and when i try to run my got i get this:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   ''@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)

and the ip that I use is not even that is 172.17.0.3. The database runs in docker if that helps. 
I have already tried to change the ip and that doesn't change the error in any way.

Comment: Try without Clojure to sort out this issue. E.g. connect via a SQL client.

Comment: What DB config do you use to connect? (db spec, url etc)

Comment: (db/defdb production
    (db/mysql {:db "dbname"
            :username "root"
            :password "password"
            :host "172.17.0.3"
            :port "3306"})) I tried it in repl and it connected. I have search in all the files and the .0.1 ip is not anywhere.